Tikz-graphic: Change the direction of the naming of the edge and the size of the numbers in the index
How can I change the direction of the naming of the AGE and the size of the numbers in the index for the following code?
I modified one of the answers to a different question to get the result: Answer link
    \documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      mycircle/.style={
         circle,
         draw=black,
         fill=black,
         fill opacity = 0.99,
         text opacity=1,
         inner sep=0.5pt,
         minimum size=9pt,
         font=\tiny},
      myarrow/.style={-Stealth},
      node distance=0.8cm and 1.4cm
      ]
      \node[mycircle] (c1) {\textcolor{white}{1}};
      \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c2) {\textcolor{white}{2}};
      \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c3) {\textcolor{white}{3}};
      \node[mycircle,below right=of c2] (c4) {\textcolor{white}{4}};

    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
     c2/c3/$e_3$/above,
      c1/c2/$e_1$/above,
       c1/c3/$e_2$/below, 
       c2/c4/$e_4$/above,
       c3/c4/$e_5$/below}
       \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,\p] {\txt} (\j);


     % draw this outside loop to get proper orientation of 10
     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The output is in the form

Is it possible to change the size of the numbers in the index to be consistent?
Is it possible to change the naming direction of line $e_3$ to be the same as all?
Is it possible to change the size of the arrow head?
The changes are in the form

Please help, thank you very much

Don't use sloped for that label.

@cfr Is it possible to modify the code in the answer to give the required result?

Please attribute/link code if you didn't author it. I'm assuming from the comment that you did not. my apologies if i'm mistaken.

@cfr I modified one of the answers to a different question to get the result in the question above: Answer link  link

please edit your question to include it. comments are ephemeral by design.

Don't use sloped for that label. Either handle it on its own or incorporate a test or add another variable.
Not entirely certain what the issue with the arrow is, but I wouldn't use positioning syntax here, at least without overriding the anchor afterwards. Perhaps something like this?
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mycircle/.style={
    circle,
    draw=black,
    fill=black,
    fill opacity = 0.99,
    text opacity=1,
    inner sep=0.5pt,
    minimum size=9pt,
    text=white,
    font=\tiny},
  myarrow/.style={-Stealth},
  node distance=0.8cm and 1.4cm
  ]
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \foreach \i [count=\n] in {(180:1.5),(90:1),(-90:1),(0:1.5)}
  \node [mycircle] (c\n) at \i {\n};
  
  \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p/\q [expand list=true] in {% start node/end node/text/position
    c2/c3/$e_3$/right/,
    c1/c2/$e_1$/above/sloped,
    c1/c3/$e_2$/below/sloped, 
    c2/c4/$e_4$/above/sloped,
    c3/c4/$e_5$/below/sloped}
  \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[font=\tiny,\p,\q] {\txt} (\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Isn't it also better to change font=\tiny to font=\scriptsize

@pascal974 well, that wasn't asked. define 'better' ;). personally, I would likely change them, but I don't know what this represents or whether additional elements are yet to be added.
